# List all files in all subdirectories NOT having specified file permissions

Tags: command-line, shell, grep

I need to see all files (with full pathname), along with their file permissions, on a folder which DO NOT match

```
-rw-r--r--
```

This didn't work as I thought it should have:

```
#ls -laR | grep --invert-match '-rw-r--r--'
grep: invalid option -- -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to backquote all `-`:

```
#ls -laR | grep --invert-match '\-rw\-r\-\-r\-\-'
```

Comment: Or you can just put `--` before the pattern.

Comment: Hi - this actually gave me the right output... the others were showing the opposite of what was needed...

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 \! -perm 0664 -printf '%M\t%P\n'
```

Modify format string as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -laR | grep -- "-rw-r--r--"
```

but you really should use GNU `find`.